# Create A Page At Root And Set As Home Page

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-server

I am trying to iterate all the site collections and webs in a web application, create a blank page at the root, and set it to the home page. Setting the home page is no problem, but how to create a blank file at the root of each web, and set it to the home page? Below is my current effort.

```
$siteUrl = Read-Host "Enter Site URL"
$rootSite = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($siteUrl)
$spWebApp = $rootSite.WebApplication

foreach($site in $spWebApp.Sites)
{

$webs= $site.AllWebs
try
{
    foreach ($web in $webs)
    {
        Write-Host $web.url


        $folder = $web.RootFolder
        $folder.WelcomePage = "test.aspx"
    }
}
catch
{
    write-host -f Red "error" $_.exception
    $errorlabel = $true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out. Allows you to create a new page in a page library. You can then set it as the welcome page.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18380019/how-to-create-a-page-in-a-given-sharepoint-2010-pages-library-using-powershell

Comment: how if it isn't a publishing site?